# fade in/fade out mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, fadein, fadeout

I'm trying to click a thumbnail and fadeout the same image of the thumbnail but the fullsize version (its a cloth gallery) and fadein another one, the thing its that it works on desktop but in mobile only execute the .css actions but inst executing the hide and show and i dont know why =S. Here is the code that i'm using.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#miniaturas li').bind("tap click", function () {

        var idName = $(this).attr('name');
        //#miniaturas are the thumbnails
        $('#miniaturas li').css('border', '1px solid #CCC');
        $(this).css("border", "1px solid #555555");

        //#imagen-articulo are the fullsize images
        $('#imagen-articulo a img').hide();
        $('#imagen-articulo a img#' + idName).fadeIn(1000);

    });

});
```

I'll apreciate your help guys!

Comment: Try using touchstart instead of tap and you can change bind with on. And as I can see from the code you don't even need 2 events for this, click should work just fine :)

Comment: I tried and same result, only execute the .css but the .fadein and .fadeout ins't working on mobile =(

Comment: If it applies the css mods then it should work for hide and fadeIn. You have some other issue preventing it from happening.  Show more of your code or  make a fiddle with your issue :)

Comment: its dificult show more code because the site its too big, and its hard to find the issue and there is no much scripts for mobile =(